# Scalar Function Coalesce Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I am trying to get a scalar function to work that combines all the rows of display values.

When I run my distinct query I get results I expect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [tblMSC_Notes].[Display] 
FROM [tblMSC_Notes]
INNER JOIN [tblUnits_Notes] ON [tblUnits_Notes].[NotesID] = [tblMSC_Notes].[NoteID]
WHERE (([tblMSC_Notes].[Display] IS NOT NULL) AND ([tblUnits_Notes].[UnitID] = 15)) 
ORDER BY [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]
```

Rows Displayed:

```
♦
ML
No Cloak
```

What I am trying to do now is output the Display as a single field "♦, ML, No Cloak"

Looking at the various examples I think I am close but I keep getting errors with the query:

```
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(Max)

    SET @Result = ''

    WITH Display_CTE (Display)
    AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]
        FROM [tblMSC_Notes]
        INNER JOIN [tblUnits_Notes] ON [tblUnits_Notes].[NotesID] = [tblMSC_Notes].[NoteID]
        WHERE (([tblMSC_Notes].[Display] IS NOT NULL) AND ([tblUnits_Notes].[UnitID] = @UnitID)) 
        ORDER BY [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]
    )

    SET @Result = (SELECT COALESCE(@Result  + ', ','') as DisplayResult
    FROM (
        SELECT [tblMSC_Notes].[Display] 
        FROM [tblMSC_Notes]
        WHERE [Display] IN (SELECT Display FROM Display_CTE) 
        ORDER BY [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]
        )
    )

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Result

END
```

I was going to make this a scalar function in another query.

Here is some sample data from the tblMSC_Notes table:

```
ID UnitID NotesID
1  1513   154 
2  1513   154
3  5032   152
4  5032   155
5  5033   152 
6  5033   155 
7  5033    43 
8  5034    43 
9  5034   152 
10 5034   155 
11 5035   152 
12 5035   155 
13 5035    43
```

Here is join using the Note ID

```
ID UnitID NotesID Display 
1  1513       154 LB 
2  1513       154 LB 
3  5032       152 AL 
4  5032       155 PL 
5  5033       152 AL 
6  5033       155 PL 
7  5033        43 N 
8  5034        43 N
9  5034       152 AL
10 5034       155 PL
```

Mohd - Thanks for the help so I would just need to change my create function to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnAnnex03_MasterShipChart_Notes] ( 
-- Add the parameters for the function here 
@UnitID int 
) 
RETURNS nvarchar(Max) 
AS 
BEGIN 
-- Declare the return variable here 
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(Max) 
SET @Result = ''

SET @Result = (SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT [tblMSC_Notes].[Display], ',') FROM [tblMSC_Notes] INNER JOIN [tblUnits_Notes] ON [tblUnits_Notes].[NotesID] = [tblMSC_Notes].[NoteID] WHERE (([tblMSC_Notes].[Display] IS NOT NULL) AND ([tblUnits_Notes].[UnitID] = @UnitID)) ORDER BY [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]) 

-- Return the result of the function 
RETURN @Result 
END 
GO
```

Comment: please tag DBMS you're using, indeed even if it suggests SQL Server as of formatting style.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a FIDDLE for this example with data.

You just need to use string_agg in this query as below:

```
SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT [tblMSC_Notes].[Display], ',')
        FROM [tblMSC_Notes]
        INNER JOIN [tblUnits_Notes] ON [tblUnits_Notes].[NotesID] = [tblMSC_Notes].[NoteID]
        WHERE (([tblMSC_Notes].[Display] IS NOT NULL) AND ([tblUnits_Notes].[UnitID] = @UnitID)) 
        ORDER BY [tblMSC_Notes].[Display]
```

Comment: @KenKazinski please edit the question with the information you provided in this section, rather than commenting...

Comment: Barbaros - is that what you meant by "in this section?"